# Bootstrap 4.3.1 Popover Does Not Display Table Inside Popover Content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a Bootstrap 4.3.1 Popover with a Table embedded inside the content. Everything is displayed but the table is not. In the below code, I've tried both the function for `content` as well as directly `$('#a02').html()`.

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true,    
    content: function() { return $('#a02').html(); },  // Also tried directly without function
    title: 'Test'
  }).click(function() {
   $(this).popover('show');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="right">
   Click Here for Popover
</a>

<div id="a02" style="display: none;">
   Some text before table
   <div>
      <table width="100%">
          <thead>
              <th>Column 1</th>
              <th>Column 2</th>
              <th>Column 3</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Some people have tried showing me a JSFiddle that works with Bootstrap 3. I took their JSFiddle and merely changed the Bootstrap refs to 4, and it broke. 
[Bootstrap 3 JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/irmoathlete/mk4wjz5f/) | [Bootstrap 4 JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejvfL97x/)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Tooltips and Popovers use a built-in sanitizer to sanitize options which accept HTML

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer

try this:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.table = [];
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.tr = [];
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.td = [];
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.th = [];
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.div = [];
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.tbody = [];
    $.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.thead = [];

  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
      return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
      return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: But why doesn't it sanitize other HTML tags like `<div>`? What's so special about `<table>`? I didn't have to whitelist `<div>` for it to show that HTML -- in fact I mimicked the table with a DIV-table successfully..

Comment: This should definitely be documented somewhere more prominently. Just costed me half an hour.

Comment: Yeah, cost me an hour too. This should be the correct answer. thank you.

Comment: Missing `th` in the answer, otherwise perfect!

Comment: I modified Biri's answer and added `<TH>` to his answer. Hopefully it looks complete now. Biri, I hope you don't mind!

Comment: benefit of encountering this problem after 11mos is that this page already ranked on google, costed me only 5mins. thank you for your time. Here's my minified version on the whitelisting part: `var el = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Default.whiteList; el.table = el.tr = el.td = el.th = el.div = el.tbody = el.thead = [];`

Comment: Cost me 2 days... And that's on top of all the other changes due to the migration from Bootstrap 3...

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to use `$.fn.popover.Constructor.DEFAULTS.whiteList.table = []`, etc.

Comment: Tested this and it seems to work on bootstrap 3 also. I wasted almost 4 hours because apparently this answer is not ranked very high by search engines

Comment: People using Bootstrap 5 should replace $.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList. [...] with bootstrap.Tooltip.Default.allowList. [...] for every allowed HTML tag.

Comment: Note that in Bootstrap 5.x (I'm working with 5.3.x) "whiteList" is changed to "allowList"

Answer (score 22):

There's nothing wrong with biri's answer, but just so you know (because it's also badly documented), you can deactivate the entire sanitizer if you want to.

```
$(function() {
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    sanitize: false,
  });
});
```

*UPDATE:* What do you know? [It's documented](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/#options) by now:

```
+----------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| Name     | Type    | Default | Description                            |
+----------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| sanitize | boolean | true    | Enable or disable the sanitization. If |
|          |         |         | activated 'template', 'content' and    |
|          |         |         | 'title' options will be sanitized.     |
+----------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Interestingly, even setting sanitize to false it wasn't displaying the table. Using bootstrap 4.5.3. Whitelisting the table html tags did the trick

Answer (score 2):

For some how **table** not working inside popover, but you can use other tags like `ul`. I just update the with `ul` i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true,    
    content: function() { return $('#a02').html(); },  // Also tried directly without function
    title: 'Test',
  }).click(function() {
   $(this).popover('show');
  });
```

```css
.popover-html ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.popover-html ul li {  
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 33%;
}

.popover-html ul li + li {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="right">
   Click Here for Popover
</a>

<div id="a02" style="display: none;">
   Some text before table <div class='popover-html'><ul><li>Column 1</li><li>Column 2</li><li>Column 3</li></ul><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul></div>
```

Another option you can add **HTML** in **data-content** attribute. Thanks

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```

```css
.popover-html ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.popover-html ul li {  
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 33%;
}

.popover-html ul li + li {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a tabindex="0"
   class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
   role="button" 
   data-html="true" 
   data-toggle="popover" 
   data-trigger="focus" 
   title="Test" 
   data-content="Some text before table<div class='popover-html'><ul><li>Column 1</li><li>Column 2</li><li>Column 3</li></ul><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul></div>">Click Here for Popover</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like so:

```
$(function() {
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
      return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
      return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
    }
  });
});
```

```
<!-- Popover #1 -->
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-popover-content="#a1" data-placement="right">Popover Example</a>


<!-- Content for Popover #1 -->
<div id="a1" class="hidden">
  <div class="popover-heading">Title</div>
  <div class="popover-body">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Link to Popover Bootstrap 4.0 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#options)
UPDATE: 
[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/irmoathlete/mk4wjz5f/)

Comment: I can, but why doesn't my code work? It works for everything other than Tables. It also works in earlier versions of Bootstrap.

Comment: One other thing, why is the formatting of the table off? By default, everything should be aligned into rows.

Comment: @geneb. I have updated the answer to match what you have wanted. Please review.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running the same code and it's not working. You linked a JSFiddle with Bootstrap v3.2.0 if you look at the CDN reerence. But mine is 4.3.2. I claim that with 4.3.2 the updated code above is not working.

Comment: This does not work for me either with Bootstrap 4.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class=".." data-bs-toggle="popover"  data-bs-trigger="hover"  data-bs-html="true" data-bs-animation="false" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-content=".." title=".."></div>
```

Adding  data-bs-animation="false" solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap above 3.4 version has a sanitization of HTML tags and attributes before it will be displayed in the popover or tooltip content. so make sure you add the tags and attributes to the whitelist if it is not present in the default whitelist.

The default whitelist has been listed here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#js-sanitizer

The new tags to the white list can be added below

// To allow tags to display in pop-over body we need to whitelist the tags which is not present in the default whitelist. // Currently table and it's children is not whitelisted by default // So i am adding table tags along with other required tags

```
var myDefaultWhiteList = $.fn.popover.Constructor.DEFAULTS.whiteList
myDefaultWhiteList.table = []
myDefaultWhiteList.tbody = []
myDefaultWhiteList.tr = []
myDefaultWhiteList.td = []
myDefaultWhiteList.th = []
```

// To allow tags attributes we can add like this myDefaultWhiteList.td = ['data-option']

You can also add your tag to display the HTML content in the popover body