# How to configure the boostrap sanitizer in scalajs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scala.js

I am using a bootstrap popover that has a canvas tag as part of its content. I had no idea why the canvas tag did not appear until I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362609/bootstrap-4-3-1-popover-does-not-display-table-inside-popover-content).

So I guess I need to run the following javascript code:

```
$.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.canvas = [];
```

How can I do this in scalajs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
import scala.scalajs.js

js.Dynamic.global.$.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.canvas = js.Array()
```

Comment: When using the jquery-facade library this will not work as it causes a TypeError. See my answer below for a way of getting around this

Answer (score 1):

I tried using:

```
js.Dynamic.global.$.fn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.canvas = js.Array()
```

But it causes the following error

> TypeError: $g.$ is undefined

I guess this is related to the fact that I am using the querki jquery-facade. So this led me to the following solution which does work:

```
    $.fn.asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[js.Object]]("popover")
    .asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[js.Object]]("Constructor")
    .asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[js.Object]]("Default")
    .asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[js.Object]]("whiteList")
    .asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[js.Object]].put("canvas", js.Array())
```

I added the following implicit class

```
implicit class ObjectEnhancer(obj: js.Object) {

    class DynamicDict(obj: js.Object) extends Dynamic {

        private val dict = obj.asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[js.Object]]

        def selectDynamic(name: String) = new DynamicDict(dict(name))

        def updateDynamic(name: String)(value: js.Object) = dict.put(name, value)
    }

    def asDyn = new DynamicDict(obj)
}
```

Which allows me to write this in a cleaner way:

```
    $.fn.asDyn.popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.canvas = js.Array()
```

Comment: Using a mix of my solution and yours, you could probably write `$.fn.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].popover.Constructor.Default.whiteList.canvas = js.Array()`, without having to define `ObjectEnhancer`.