# Why is this popover not displaying info from an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Here I have a popover with a 1 second delay to display user profile info when hovering over a link to that user's profile.

```
             $(function() {
                 var timer = null;
                 var xhr = null;
                 $('.user_popup').hover(
                     function(event) {
                         //mouse in event handler
                         var elem = $(event.currentTarget);
                         timer = setTimeout(function() {
                             timer = null;
                             xhr = $.ajax(
                                 '/user/' + elem.first().text().trim() + '/popup').done(
                                     function(data) {
                                         xhr = null;
                                         elem.popover({
                                             trigger: 'manual',
                                             html: true,
                                             animation: false,
                                             container: elem,
                                             content: data
                                         }).popover('show');
                                       flask_moment_render_all();
                                     }
                                 );
                         }, 1000);
                     },
```

It is appearing and disappearing correctly but doesn't populate with the data called by ajax, which is an HTML table.

The debugger indicates that the call works and `data` shows the info I want obtained from another route in my app.

If I replace the `content' option with a hardcoded string, this does display correctly. So I know it is something to do with the ajax call.

Comment: Does replacing by static text `content: 'HOWDY'` works?

Comment: @Viney yes that works

Comment: Then something do with `data`, what does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: @Viney That shows exactly what I want, which is an html table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the popover is not displaying is due to Bootstrap 4's  [inbuilt sanitizer for popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer).

The html data retrieved from the ajax call was a table and this was being blocked by the sanitizer, hence the empty popover.

This can be resolved by adding `sanitize: false` as an attribute to your code or by adding to the default whitelist as in the documentation.

[See this previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362609/bootstrap-4-3-1-popover-does-not-display-table-inside-popover-content)